# how to implement the feature where the lazy column scrolls a single column at a time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I want to create the reels feature with the lazy columns in kotlin where user can scroll the single item at a time not the multiple one's.

I tried to use the

```
   flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(
                snapLayoutInfoProvider = SnapLayoutInfoProvider(state)
            )
```

this code can snap the item but can't stop the user from scrolling multiple items at a time
I tried to use the pager but the pager performance is not as much good as the lazy columns.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the purpose of the Pager is to do this kind of things and it comes with more functionalities you can use and also efficient and easy to implement. But in case if you still want to do same with `LazyColumn` then we have to implement our own scrolling behaviour. And, you can done this by following these simple steps:

**Step 1:** Set `userScrollEnabled` to `false` so that user cannot do the default scrolling.

**Step 2:** Pass the `state` to the `LazyColumn` using `rememberLazyListState` by saving it in different variable as we will use it later.

**Step 3:** Now set the `modifier` for drag gestures as shown in the code and then you can try out the feature.

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
var currentIndex = 0
var job: Job? = null

LazyColumn(
    state = lazyListState,
    userScrollEnabled = false, // to restrict the default scrolling behaviour
    modifier = Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consume()
                val (x,y) = dragAmount
                
                // cancelling the previous job
                job?.cancel()
                job = coroutineScope.launch{
                    // Waiting for next gesture changes
                    delay(100)
                    
                    // Although we don't need right and left swipes
                    when {
                        x > 0 -> { /* swiped right */ }
                        x < 0 -> { /* swiped left */ }
                    }
                    when {
                        y > 0 -> { /* swiped down */
                            try { lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(--currentIndex) }
                            catch (e: Exception) { /* handle the error */}
                        }
                        y < 0 -> { /* swiped up */
                            try { lazyListState.animateScrollToItem(++currentIndex) }
                            catch (e: Exception) { /* handle the error */}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
) {
    // List content...
}
```

*NOTE: In this logic the `currentIndex` can you beyond the limits but the app will not crashed so you can also handle these edge cases.*

You might came up with the question why we have done job assignment and cancellation. So the reason is that the gestures changes multiple time rapidly and due to this it can do multiple scrolling so to counter this we have used **Debounce Technique**. You can check more about in one of my solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76968173/14972910

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the smooth scroll behaviour like the ViewPager2. I don't want to block the user interaction.

Comment: @AnasMirza And that's what I was saying that Pager library comes with great functionalities and is also performance efficient so if you want exact same functionality like pager then you should implement the same as the `LazyColumn` will work with it's own efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, Just one more thing to confirm: Can the pager manage a large amount of data like the viewPager2 or lazyColumn?

Comment: @AnasMirza You can optimize synchronisation of data from server and also optimize UI by following some best practices like `SideEffect`, `DisposalEffect`, etc. and hence, the performance can be maximised.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I handled the issue, so maybe works for you case also;

First of all, define necessary variables;

```
val lazyStackState = rememberLazyListState()
val lazyStackScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

val positionInLayout = SnapPositionInLayout { layoutSize, itemSize, itemIndex ->
    // This value tells where to snap on the x axis within the viewport
    // Setting it to 0 results in snapping of the first visible item to the left side (or right side if RTL)
    0
}

val snappingLayout = remember(lazyStackState) { SnapLayoutInfoProvider(lazyStackState, positionInLayout) }
val snapBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(snappingLayout)
```

After that, create a `LaunchedEffect` to trigger your action in case users swipe up. The thing here is prevent more than one swipes at a time by using `scrollToItem(1)` logic.
Also, if you are using a shimmer item at the end and load new data when you reach the shimmer item, you may need to use `scrollToItem(0)` at the end to make it work also when new data arrives.

```
LaunchedEffect(isSwipedUp) {
    if (isSwipedUp) {
        lazyStackScope.launch {
            if (listData.size > 1) {
                lazyStackState.scrollToItem(1)
            }
            // Your extra logic if you need
            if (listData.isEmpty()) {
                lazyStackState.scrollToItem(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, assign `isSwipedUp.not()` results in `userScrollEnabled` parameter for LazyColumn

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .heightIn(1500.dp)
        .background(White),
    userScrollEnabled = isSwipedUp.not(),
    state = lazyStackState,
    flingBehavior = snapBehavior,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
) {
    items(
        items = listData,
        key = { currentData -> currentData.id!! },
        itemContent = { data ->
            val isActiveItem = listData.firstOrNull()?.id == data.id
            // Use your content here
        }
   )
}
```

Hope it helps